# Get available memory for a process

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I use Delphi 2007, so there is a 32-bit limit of available memory.

Using the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` PE flag, there should be a 3 GB limit instead of 2 GB:

```
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE} // Allows usage of more than 2GB memory
```

This is the method I use to get the current memory usage of the process:

```
function MemoryUsed: Int64;
var
  PMC: _PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX;
begin
  Win32Check(GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess, @PMC, SizeOf(PMC)));
  Result := PMC.PrivateBytes;
end;
```

Now I want a way to get the total amount of available memory for the process. It should be around 3 GB. But I don't want to hardcode it, as in the future we will move to new Delphi and 64-bit.

What Win32 API function should I use?

**Available memory** - Computers available memory - Maybe 8 GB RAM is installed. If more is required the OS start to swap memory to disk.

**Process available memory** - A limitation in executable and Windows. Now most Windows is 64-bit so that is not a problem. But if executable is compiled as 32-bit with `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`, the limit should be 3 GB, right? When executable is 64-bit, it will be much larger, maybe 64 GB (but then swapping may happen if installed RAM is less...).

So my question is, how can I get the process's available memory?

Comment: Define available memory please. Your process can use the full 4gb address space on your 64 bit system. It's able to allocate all of that space which is not currently reserved, give or take. What are you going to do with the information anyway.

Comment: I try to clarify the question

Comment: So it's the amount of address space that you want. It's either 2, 3 or 4. Very unlikely to be 3. You won't find many 32 bit systems booted with the /3gb switch these days.

Comment: Ok, you are correct. In some way I thought that the process have 3 GB available. But when I test I manage to get 3,85  GB. So 4 GB is the limit. Great!

Comment: On a 32 bit system it will still be 2GB, but they are very rare these days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of obvious things you can do. Call [`GetSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381.aspx) and subtract [`lpMinimumApplicationAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958.aspx) from [`lpMaximumApplicationAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958.aspx) to find the amount of address space available to your process.

The amount of physical memory available to you is much harder to obtain, and is not a fixed quantity. You are competing with all the other processes for that, and so this is a very fluid and dynamic concept. You can find out how much physical memory is available on the system by calling [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589.aspx). That returns other information too but it's very easy to misinterpret it. In fact this API will also tell you how much virtual memory is available to your process which would give you the same information as in the first paragraph.

Perhaps what you want is the minimum of the total physical and total virtual memory. But I would not like to say. I've seen many examples of code that needlessly limits its ability to perform by taking bad decisions based on misinterpreted memory statistics.

Comment: Should it not lpMaximumApplicationAddress?